# Comparing two fields in a form in Javascript - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  my comparePasswords() is not working...

```
        <script>

            function comparePasswords()
            {
                if (post-form.password.value != post-form.password2.value)
                {
                    $('passwordShow').innerHTML = '';
                }
                else
                {
                    $('passwordShow').innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match';
                }
            }
        </script>


<form id="post-form" action="signup.php" method="post" >

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" onkeyup="testPassword(this.value);" maxlength="50" size="25" tabindex="102" value="">

<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" onkeyup="comparePasswords();" maxlength="50" size="25" tabindex="104" value="">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

```
document.getElementById('password').value
```

and

```
document.getElementById('password2').value
```

Also, your logic is wrong. The first conditional block will fire if the passwords do not match.

**EDIT**

seems you are using jQuery, so simply use

```
$('#password').val()
```

to get the field's value.

You should also set the innerHTML using jQuery (may as well) with the `html()` method

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how you're accessing the form object.

```
post-form.password
```

To the javascript engine, this is the same as this:

```
post - (form.password)
```

Also, you'd have to give your form a `name` attribute (not just an id) to access it that way. If you wanted to access it by name, you'd use something like this:

```
document['post-form'].password
```

Or by id:

```
document.getElementById("post-form");
```

Comment: 15 chars? heh                                                         e

Comment: :)                                  !

Answer (score 0):

The test in your if is backwards. The first branch is testing if the two passwords are NOT equal to each other.